# Maze hits error on test cases due to grid conversion

Tags: python

My BFS Maze works correctly within it's own class by solving the maze using a neighbor and evaluating neighbors using BFS. I have test cases that were supplied to me, which I cannot change, but my test fails all of the sample tests and I don't understand.

Initially, I thought my issue was in the translation between grid components like `(1,0)` or `(0,1)` for direction to `str` like `N` for north because the test only checks for the correct `str` direction, not the grid. It took me a very long time testing the translation (working with someone on here) but now I'm certain the issue lies somewhere else but I have no idea where.

Here is my BFS maze solver:

```
    def moves(self):
        moves = list()
        dir_to_str = {
            (-1, 0): 'W',
            (1, 0): 'E',
            (0, -1): 'S',
            (0, 1): 'N',
        }
        (r, c) = self.location
        for (dr, dc) in [(-1, 0), (1, 0), (0, -1), (0, 1)]:  # up, down, left, right
            if self.grid[r + dr][c + dc] != 'X':
                moves.append(dir_to_str[(dr, dc)])
        return moves
```

It will print the agent as it transverses the maze using BFS successfully.

The issue is when I import it into a BFS test case (which I cannot change). None of the tests pass. Each get an error that I don't understand, and here are the failures:

```
Ran 3 tests in 0.044s

FAILED (failures=3)


['S',
 'S',
 'E',
 'E',
 'E',
 'E',
 'E',
 'E',
 'S',
 'S',
 'E',
 'E',
 'E',
 'E',
 'E',
 'S',
 'S',
 'S',
 'E',
 'E',
 'S',
 'E',
 'E',
 'S',
 'S',
 'S',
 'S',
 'S',
 'E',
 'E',
 'S',
 'S',
 'S',
 'S',
 'S'] != ['E',
 'E',
 'N',
 'N',
 'E',
 'E',
 'N',
 'N',
 'E',
 'E',
 'N',
 'N',
 'N',
 'E',
 'N',
 'N',
 'N',
 'N',
 'N',
 'N',
 'E',
 'N',
 'N',
 'E',
 'E',
 'E',
 'E',
 'E',
 'N',
 'N',
 'E',
 'E',
 'E',
 'E',
 'E']
```

Comment: The error means "The expected answer is `S, S, E, E, E, E, etc`, but your code instead says `E, E, N, N, E, E, etc`". It's obvious that your answer is incorrect because two steps east and two steps north takes you through the top wall of the test case. Please trace out your path on the mace and have a look.

Comment: @user12027316 I rolled back to the first version of the code, even though it was a bit verbose. The update is OK and does cut to the chase retroactively, so it's still useful for future visitors, but it also loses a *lot* of info and context in the process so I think it does damage the quality of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mixing up rows and columns is a common error in working with grids. The data structure `dir_to_str` doesn't match the rest of the code because it uses the first tuple element as the column (horizontal/x-axis).

Change:

```
dir_to_str = {
    (-1, 0): 'W',
    (1, 0): 'E',
    (0, -1): 'S',
    (0, 1): 'N',
}
```

to

```
dir_to_str = {
    (-1, 0): 'N',
    (1, 0): 'S',
    (0, -1): 'W',
    (0, 1): 'E',
}
```

and the resulting `path` becomes:

['S', 'S', 'E', 'E', 'S', 'S', 'E', 'E', 'S', 'S', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'S', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'S', 'E', 'E', 'S', 'S','S', 'S', 'S', 'E', 'E', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S']

This still doesn't match the output because your code takes a slightly different route than the test suite.

You can fix this by changing the priority of your search:

```
for (dr, dc) in [(-1, 0), (1, 0), (0, -1), (0, 1)]:
```

becomes

```
for dr, dc in [(0, 1), (-1, 0), (1, 0), (0, -1)]:  # east first
```

Then you get

['S', 'S', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'S', 'S', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'E', 'E', 'S', 'E', 'E', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'E', 'E', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S']

After all of this, I recommend a refactor to remove the [hard-coded literals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_coding) scattered throughout the code. By centralizing the directional logic into one data structure for the entire class, it makes bugs like this easier to avoid and hunt down.

Comment: I removed the extra code because I didn't want people having an entire answer to a BFS maze problem, as I'm afraid it will lead others to cheat when given the assignment.